# Stop Ajax Request And Call New Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

in this code, i take typing character from user and search it in database,but when user enter each character,running new ajax request with  previous ajax,

i want when call search function, cancel previous ajax request and run new ajax request;

html code :

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="search()">
```

js code:

```
    function search () {


    var request=$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/h.php",
        data: {k_word:k_word},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {    

          ghtml(data)       

      }
  })


 }
```

Also i tried with abrot() like this :

```
var request;

 function search () {

    request.abort();


     request=$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/h.php",
        data: {k_word:k_word},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {    

          ghtml(data)       

      }
  })


 }
```

but not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's generally not how it's done, instead throttling is used to only call the ajax function when the user stops typing for a given time

First of all, get rid of the inline javascript

```
 <input type="text" id="myInput" />
```

then use an event handler

```
$('#myInput').on('keyup', function() {

    clearTimeout( $(this).data('timer') );

    $(this).data('timer', 
        setTimeout(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type     : "POST",
                url      : "php/h.php",
                data     : {k_word:k_word},
                dataType : "json",
                success  : function (data) {    

                    ghtml(data)       

                }
            });
        }, 500)
    );
});
```

This sets a timeout on the ajax call, and that timeout is cleared if a new key is pressed within half a second, so the ajax call is only made when the user stops typing for more than 500 milliseconds

Comment: And it is important to remember that stopping the AJAX request locally WILL NOT stop the AJAX request from processing, it only stops the browser from listening for a response. This means that if you send five request and cancel the first four on the client, the first four will continue to occupy a thread on the web server until they finish processing.

Comment: @Mark - Indeed, `xhr.abort()` only aborts a request if it's not already sent to the server, when it's sent there's no way to stop it on the serverside, and that's why it's not done that way, but throttling is used instead.